# iPhone. How to change individual pixels of big CGImage inplace?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I use UIScrollView, which zooms and scrolls UIImageView, which contains UIImage, which take pixels from CGImage. 
Size of CGImage may be about 5000x2000 pixels
1) Is this a correct way to zoom and scroll big image?

Some logic may change periodically some region(rect) in that CGImage
2) How can i change individuall pixels in CGImage inplace without heawy processor usage (entire image recreation)?

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

- I create CGBitmapContext for storing big image at XRGB-format.
- Subclass UIView for override drawRect: which represent my image

periodically updates do so:

- update some rect
- invoke [setNeedsDisplayInRect: rect]

in [drawRect: rect] do:

```
  CGContextRef g = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGImageRef imgAll = CGBitmapContextCreateImage( m_BmpContext );
  CGImageRef imgRect = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect( imgAll, rect );
  CGContextDrawImage( g, rect, imgRect );
  CGImageRelease( imgRect );
  CGImageRelease( imgAll );
```

and it's work fine for me